# "To help to the project" vs. "to help with the project" vs. "to help in the project"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following is grammatical?

> - He explained how the school teachers help to the project.
> - He explained how the school teachers help with the project.
> - He explained how the school teachers help in the project.

The teachers aren't part of the project, they give info about the students' progress in school.

Comment: The correct phrase is 'He explained how the school teachers help with the project.' This question doesn't really belong here, why don't you support the proposal for [English Language Learners stack exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From OALD, it can be one of the following forms:

- Help someone with something:

> [He explained how] the school teachers help him/students/people with
>   the project.

- Help (someone) in doing something:

> [He explained how] the school teachers help (him/students/people) in doing the project.

- Help someone (to) do something:

> [He explained how] the school teachers help him/students/people (to) do the project.